# how to initialize JCOP java card for first time use

Tags: smartcard, javacard, jcop

how to write these  for initialize jcop first time use at chip 
APDU:00A4040010( TK - KEY )
APDU:00F00000 ( open for Initialize )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JCOP 0x6A82 after sending Select + Transport Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990813/jcop-0x6a82-after-sending-select-transport-key)

Comment: Please take a look at the NXP provided documentation and ask them directly if you're still having problems after reading the info. These documents are under NDA and responding to questions like these *may breach such an NDA*.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize JCOP:
This is called the pre-personalisation proces, 
that allows a simple and secure way to initialise the card for first use. 
The execution time depends on the used ROOT applet commands during the 
pre-personalization.

Supported communication protocols:

```
ISO/IEC 7816-3
T=1 direct convention [default]

ISO/IEC 7816-3
T=0 direct convention

ISO/IEC 7816-3
T=1 inverse convention

ISO/IEC 7816-3
T=0 inverse convention

ISO/IEC 14443-4A   
T=CL
```

Communication speed for contact or contactless communication can be set via
the baudrate:

Contacted (default clock rate is 3.5712 MHz):

```
9600 bit/s [Default]
19200 bit/s
38400 bit/s
57600 bit/s
115200 bit/s
223200 bit/s
```

Contactless:

```
106 kbit/s
212 kbit/s
424 kbit/s
848 kbit/s
```

The pre personalization process procedure goes as follow:

```
SELECT command with TKey
/send 00a4040010[Tkey]

BOOT
/send 00F00000

READ/WRITE command
Here you can personalize the following things:

JCRE_MODE 
GP_MODE
FEATURE_MODE1
FEATURE_MODE2
JCRE_CPLC 
IOCONFIG_IFSD 
IOCONFIG_COLD_WTX, IOCONFIG_W
ARM_WTX, IOCONFIG_TCL_WTX 
IOCONFIG_COLD_CONF, IOCONFIG_WARM_CONF 
IOCONFIG_COLD_
BAUD, IOCONFIG_WARM_BAUD 
IOCONFIG_COLD_IFLEN, 
IOCONFIG_WARM_IFLEN 
IOCONFIG_COLD_IFBYTES, 
IOCONFIG_WARM_IFBYTES 
IOCONFIG_COLD_HISTLEN, 
IOCONFIG_WARM_HISTLEN (
IOCONFIG_COLD_HIST
CHARS, IOCONFIG_W
ARM_HISTCHARS 
IOCONFIG_TCL_IFLEN 
IOCONFIG_TCL_IFBYTES 
IOCONFIG_TCL_CONF 
CM_LIFECYCLE 
CM_KEY_1, CM_KEY_2, CM_KEY_3 (
CM_KEY_1_VER, CM_KEY_2_VER, CM_KEY_3_VER 
CVM_PIN

PROTECT COMMAND
/send 00100000

FUSE command
/send 0000000000
```

For READ/WRITE commands, you need to ask your vendor.
After the pre personalization you can start using the card. Recommended is that you send a reset command after you finished the FUSE command.